# Can't seem to find how to create a fact table

Tags: olap, cube, iccube

I'm trying to design a cube with iccube and following the walkthrough, I can't seem to be able.

In the walkthrough (http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/walkthrough/walkthrough.html) when creating a dimension, there is in the picture the "Is fact indexing" option available. But, when I' trying to create a multidimensional dimension, with any table, the option is never shown. The one I have are:

- Name*
- Table*
- Unknown member
- Time dimension
- Default time dimension
- Is indexing by range

So, when I get to add the cube, it only has the calc measure section.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicolas, the option 'Is Fact Indexing' is no more available that way. To reply to your question, once you've created a cube, you need to add some Facts (see the icon on the right side when hovering over the newly created cube). Those facts are also called 'Measure Group'. A cube can have one or more 'Measure Group'; each group being attached to a table.